# No sound / No sound Via HDMI Ubuntu lts 22.04 Chuwi Herobook Air

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

*Not really for sure how to fix this one or if their is even a driver available for it. here is all the output I get. Also I am kinda of new to Ubuntu.*

*I am thinking about going back to windows 11 if I can't get this to work. It's has been very infuriating to keep trying to find driver an looks up information that does not exist.*

```
$ aplay -l 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 2: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#2 | grep -i codec
Codec: Intel Geminilake HDMI
```

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -i audio
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio [8086:3198] (rev 06)
```

```
lsmod | grep snd
snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp    28672  0
snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common    20480  1 snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi      36864  1 snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
snd_sof_pci_intel_apl    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    98304  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_apl
soundwire_intel        40960  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci            20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_apl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               143360  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_sof
snd_soc_skl           172032  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  5 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    61440  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_pci_intel_apl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          331776  8 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_soc_dmic,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         155648  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_core          110592  10 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               139264  12 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            49152  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                   102400  13 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

```
$ inxi -SA
System:
  Host: artistxoder-HeroBook-Air Kernel: 5.15.0-25-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.1 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-25-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

```
$ lspci -nnk |grep -A 1 Audio
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio [8086:3198] (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux artistxoder-HeroBook-Air 5.15.0-25-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 30 15:54:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C multimedia 
  *-multimedia              
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: e
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0e.0
       logical name: card0
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D1p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D2p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-apl latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:a1110000-a1113fff memory:a1000000-a10fffff
       *-usb:2
       description: Video
       product: icspring camera: icspring camer
       vendor: icSpring
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@1:6
       logical name: input12
       logical name: /dev/input/event3
       version: 0.01
       capabilities: usb-2.00 usb
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

```
dpkg -l | grep alsa
ii  alsa-base                                  1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7                    all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.5.1-2                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1                        all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.6-1ubuntu1                          amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                    1.20.1-1                                amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
```

```
$ grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf 
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

```
Kernal Output 
dpkg -L linux-modules-5.15.0-25-generic | grep snd
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-dummy.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-emul.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-event.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-virmidi.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-ctl-led.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hrtimer.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm-dmaengine.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-rawmidi.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-seq-device.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/pcsp/snd-pcsp.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-ens1370.ko
```

Results of alsa-info script: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=4e9ef15def84cc38bba765d540ed7f5bec051261

I also download the Wifi Driver because Ubuntu did not have on for it's here is the GitHub link. https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723du

It's really weird because the audio doesn't even show up in the system sound.
[image]